# discord.js auto role from about me (bio)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

thats my auto role from status activity, but I want change it to about me (bio). How I did it? Please help me. Thats my status activity code:

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
  const role = newPresence.guild.roles.cache.get("ROLE");
  const member = newPresence.member
  const activities = newPresence.activities[0];
  const kanal = newPresence.guild.channels.cache.get("LOG CHANNEL ID")

  if (activities && (activities.state.includes("URL"))) { 
    kanal.send({embeds: [embed.setDescription(`${member} kullanıcısı durumuna \`.gg/itopya\` ekleyerek ${role} rolünü başarıyla aldı!`).setColor("Green")]})
    return newPresence.member.roles.add(role)
  } else {
    if(member.roles.cache.get(role.id)) {
      kanal.send({embeds: [embed.setDescription(`${member} kullanıcısından urlyi kaldırdığı için ${role} rolü alındı!`).setColor("Red")]})
      newPresence.member.roles.remove(role)
    }
  }
})
```

I want this code to give a role according to the content in my section about me, but I couldn't, please help.